# How would one locate a specific book in a Bet Midrash?

Tags: torah-study, adult-learning

I am modifying this "latent" question that I asked about 2 years ago. For those who have access, you can view the original version. I'm leaving the basic topic, the same, though.

I'm comfortable learning in a *Bet Midrash*. I can locate most of the "basic" books that I need such as a Chumash, Gemarah and Ramba"m. But the Bet Midrash is filled with loads of other books, many of them commentaries - *Shitah Mekubetzet, Rabbeinu Bechayeh*, etc. I'm not sure what many of these books are for.

Occasionaly, I find a somewhat "obscure" book mentioned, such as in [this M.Y. answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/80820/5275). This is a sample. But, in general, if I saw the title of a book mentioned, and wasn't sure what "category" the book was in, how would I be able to locate this in a Bet Midrash?

View this question from a novice's standpoint. Let's say someone comes into the Bet Midrash late at night and he's pretty much there, alone. He reads the Shulchan Aruch, let's say, and it talks about some other reference that he hasn't heard of. How would he know where to look if there's no directory or catalog?

Is there any book, video or online guide or even a yeshiva that does a basic "Guide to the Bet Midrash" or something like that? What about a Yeshiva or Bet Midrash that has a computer "info database" or an information desk, like most libraries have? If not, I wonder why there isn't. Something like this would be a huge benefit to both novices and experienced people as well. How else would someone become more efficient in his own learning?

Comment: The beginning of every Artscroll masechta gives an overview of the commentaries on that masechta. That might be one place to start.

Comment: @wfb Thanks. Yes, that's useful and can be non-efficient, as well. View the question from a novice's "How do I..." viewpoint. Let's say I know what a Gemarah is but I don't know which tractate deals with how many people I should call to the Torah on Hol Hamo'ed. I don't know the meanings of the 6 *Sedarim* to even begin to narrow this down, and I don't know that I can find a quick answer in something called a "Shulchan Aruch". Should I read through possibly 63 (at least!) Art Scroll volumes to find out?

Comment: Ok, in that case I would recommend something more like this http://www.amazon.com/Reference-Guide-Talmud-Rabbi-Steinsaltz/dp/1592643124

Comment: @wfb I can't access the link, now. But I think I have that book at home. It's a huge book, but yes, I agree. It is very good! Of course, it's a guide to just the Talmud, not to the Bet Midrash, itself.

Comment: True. These books aren't really what you're looking for either but they might be helpful http://www.amazon.com/Rishonim-Biographical-prominent-ArtScroll-Judaiscope/dp/0899064523/ and http://www.amazon.com/Early-Acharonim-Biographical-Prominent-Fifteenth-Seventeenth/dp/0899064884/

Comment: I am not sure how such a guide would work. If one is a 'novice' one wouldnt be able to understand a sefer anyway. And if youre not you would know where to look. If you want to know about reading the torah you would look at a MB ( I am sure you could find it there) and from that see where the gemoro is quoted.

Comment: This question doesn't seem answerable. There isn't an easy way to tell you where everything is. It's just not how it works.

Comment: I would suggest not being too embarrassed to ask around. (לא הביישן למד) The way it works in many beis medrash/yeshiva systems is that when someone has a question, he asks the guy sitting next to him, and they might talk it out, or ask someone more knowledgable, etc. This is how people in yeshivos learn new things (and make friends in the process)

Comment: @Matt I made some edits. I got your last point. What about obscure books or if there's no one to ask. I'm trying to have some more options available. The לא הביישן למד adage is valid, but, for most novices, walking into a busy Bet Midrash can be extremely overwhelming. Place yourself in their shoes, perhaps. I'm comfy in a Bet Midrash - that I've been attending for a while. When I go to a large crowded one, I still find it overwhelming.

Comment: At Ner Yisrael Baltimore there are so many sefarim that they actually have a guide to find a Sefer somewhere in their massive Beis Midrash.

Comment: @DonielF Excellent! What type of guide is this? Online or a book / directory?

Comment: @DanF It's a book that's specific to their Beis Midrash. For one who lived in the Baltimore area, though, it could give an idea of who's a Rishon and who's an Acharon, though.

Comment: @DonielF I haven't been in Baltimore in a while. I should stop by to see this for myself.

Comment: Do you want to know categorization (Rishon vs Achaon) or layout (look in the front left corner)?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin If I were in the Bet Midrash, I'd want as much info as possible so that I can find the book quickly. Ideally, there should be a "directory" as in a library. A small Bet Midrash prob. doesn't have that, so at the least if I heard of a book called "Divrei Doniel" How would I know what category that book is?

Comment: @DanF I'm right here. You can just ask me where my Sefer is. ;)

Comment: @DanF Google. Most of the "smaller" Beis Medrashes I've been in (a room with bookshelfs lining the walls) don't have that large a selection that you're likely to find rare seforim. And those libraries which do, tend to have some kind of index.

Comment: Sounds like you should ask the person who runs the Beit Midrash. How are we supposed to answer this case-specific question?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, books are grouped by type: Halacha, Chumash, Gemarah, etc etc. So once you find, for instance, a halacha book you recognize, odds are the books in that section are the halacha books. In your example, since the Shulchan Aruch is quoting it, it's probably a halacha book that would be found in that area.

(As far as information desks and databases, Y.U. in N.Y. has an information desk in their library and, I believe, a database (access to the database may be restricted). B.M.G in Lakewood N.J. has a library-like system as well in their sforim libraries, and a written catalog of all the books.)

Comment: Good to know that some people are creating a prototype. This should be a standard. I know that smaller places this is a bit difficult.

Comment: @DanF Even the places I mentioned only have this in their libraries, not in the beis medrash itself. So it's not exactly your ideal prototype.

Comment: @DanF most small libraries are small enough that you can "figure it out" within a few days.

Comment: Maybe you and I can become pioneers on a project like this?